# C: Copying from a character array to an int

Tags: c, arrays, memcpy

```
  // Works
  int fnamesize=0;
  fnamesize=message[0]<<24;
  fnamesize+=message[1]<<16;
  fnamesize+=message[2]<<8;
  fnamesize+=message[3];

  // Doesn't work
  int fsize;
  memcpy(&fsize,message,sizeof(int));
```

Can someone explain why the second one doesn't work? The memory I'm copying from, `message` is a `char *`. When I try to test the values of fnamesize and fsize, like `printf("fsize is %d,fnamesize is %d",fsize,fnamesize);`, the fsize gives an unexpected value, but fnamesize gives the value I expect.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), which means the layout of bytes in an int.

In windows, the second way will give you an int that has the opposite byte order, like this:

```
fsize=message[3]<<24;
fsize+=message[2]<<16;
fsize+=message[1]<<8;
fsize+=message[0];
```

Comment: Absolutely right. Writing a "network stack simulator" and part of the project is working with ntoh_ and hton_. Thanks for putting me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the order of the array indices in your code that works, compare the result to the code that doesn't work, and look up the terms "big endian" and "little endian".